# How to remove commentCross with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Every time a user creates a comment, it is added using jQuery with `prepend`.

I am  trying to remove the crossIcon in certain cases but it is not removed.

```
that.find(".commentCross").css("display","none");
```

does not seem to be the correct way to do this.

How can I achieve removing `commentCross` from `$(this)` ?

```
if ("<%= user %>" != "none") {
    var i = 0;
    var postKey = "<%= post.key %>";
    var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref("comments/"+postKey).orderByChild('commenttimestamp').limitToFirst(25);
    commentsRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    var currentUserUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
    i++;
    if (childSnapshot.val().profilepic == undefined || childSnapshot.val().profilepic == null || childSnapshot.val().profilepic == "") {
        $("#commentsBox").prepend("<div class='fullComment' id='"+i+"'><a href='../../users/'"+childSnapshot.val().author+"><div class='userCommentBox'><div class='commentUsername'>"+childSnapshot.val().username+"</div><img class='userPic' src='../../../public/assets/miniProfilePic.png' /></div></a><div class='comment'>"+childSnapshot.val().text+"</div><div><img data-author='"+ childSnapshot.val().author +"' data-post='"+postKey+"' data-comment='"+childSnapshot.key+"'class='commentCross' src='./../../public/assets/cross.png'><img class='replyIcon' data-author='"+ childSnapshot.val().author +"' data-comment='"+childSnapshot.key+"' src='./../../public/assets/replyIcon.png'></div>");
        var that = $(this);
        var commentAuthor = childSnapshot.val().author;
        if (currentUserUid !== commentAuthor) {
            that.find(".commentCross").css("display","none");
        }
```

Comment: What would be scope of `$(this)` here? Could you add bit more relating code?

Comment: why not directly remove html of crossIcon from `prepend()`?And `I am trying to remove the crossIcon in certain cases`->what are the cases?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Fair enough, let me add more context

Comment: @GuruprasadRao To my knowledge, $(this) should refer to the .fullComment div

Comment: @AlivetoDie Question edited.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Question edited.

Comment: No.. `$(this)` wouldn't be `.fullComment` here.. Could you please `console.log($(this))` and see what's actually getting there.. I've worked on `Firebase` with `android` and not much touch on web app. But yea.. I can help you with `jquery`..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao "THAT :[object Object]" I don't know which properties of the object to use to get more info

Comment: instead of `var that = $(this);` what you can do is put the whole appending string in a `var` and convert it as `jquery object` and assign it to `that`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Sorry, I had forgotten I had an id I set for something else that I can use to select the element. All fixed ^^ Thank you for your help.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like below:-

```
if (childSnapshot.val().profilepic == undefined || childSnapshot.val().profilepic == null || childSnapshot.val().profilepic == "") {
    var commentAuthor = childSnapshot.val().author;
    if (currentUserUid !== commentAuthor) {
        /*remove commentCross html */

        $("#commentsBox").prepend("<div class='fullComment' id='"+i+"'><a href='../../users/'"+childSnapshot.val().author+"><div class='userCommentBox'><div class='commentUsername'>"+childSnapshot.val().username+"</div><img class='userPic' src='../../../public/assets/miniProfilePic.png' /></div></a><div class='comment'>"+childSnapshot.val().text+"</div><div><img class='replyIcon' data-author='"+ childSnapshot.val().author +"' data-comment='"+childSnapshot.key+"' src='./../../public/assets/replyIcon.png'></div>");

    }else{
       /* Add commentCross Html */

        $("#commentsBox").prepend("<div class='fullComment' id='"+i+"'><a href='../../users/'"+childSnapshot.val().author+"><div class='userCommentBox'><div class='commentUsername'>"+childSnapshot.val().username+"</div><img class='userPic' src='../../../public/assets/miniProfilePic.png' /></div></a><div class='comment'>"+childSnapshot.val().text+"</div><div><img data-author='"+ childSnapshot.val().author +"' data-post='"+postKey+"' data-comment='"+childSnapshot.key+"'class='commentCross' src='./../../public/assets/cross.png'><img class='replyIcon' data-author='"+ childSnapshot.val().author +"' data-comment='"+childSnapshot.key+"' src='./../../public/assets/replyIcon.png'></div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work, but I was hoping for a DRYer solution :)

Comment: Nevermind, I had forgotten I had already set an id for this specific purpose. Your solution works anyway, so I will accept it and upvote it. Have a nice day ^^

Comment: @TheProgrammer  glad to help you :):)